# How to add active class to specific element?

Tags: vue.js

I have this methods :

```
  methods: {

          replyBox: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
             this.isActive = !this.isActive;
           );
         },
```

In view i have this:

```
<div class="comment_list" v-for="comment in all_comments">
<a href="#" class="initial" v-on:click="replyBox">REPLY</a>

   <div id="reply-box-@{{comment.id}}" class="reply-box" v-bind:class="{active: isActive}">
             <div class="user_comment row">
               <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                 <div class="user_profile_image {{ isset($current_user->personal_user) ? 'bg_blue' : 'bg_green'}}">
                   @if(isset($current_user->avatar) && $current_user->avatar != '')
                   <img src="{{ avatar_path($current_user->avatar)}}" alt="" />
                 @else
                   <img src="{{ home_asset('img/user_icon.png') }}" alt="" />
                 @endif
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                 <textarea  class="comment_input" placeholder="Join the discussion..." @keydown.enter.prevent="postComment({{$current_user->id}}, {{$article->id}})" v-model.trim="reply_comment"></textarea>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Now what i want is to add class active only for element that is near reply link. In jquery i could use `this` and that find siblings but how can i do that in vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could add an additional property to the comment you could do the following:

Template:

```
  <div class="comment_list" v-for="comment in all_comments">
    <a href="#" class="initial" v-on:click.prevent="replyBox(comment)">REPLY</a>

    <div id="reply-box-@{{comment.id}}" class="reply-box" v-bind:class="{active: comment.isActive}">
      <div class="user_comment row">
       <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
         <div class="user_profile_image {{ isset($current_user->personal_user) ? 'bg_blue' : 'bg_green'}}">
           @if(isset($current_user->avatar) && $current_user->avatar != '')
           <img src="{{ avatar_path($current_user->avatar)}}" alt="" />
         @else
           <img src="{{ home_asset('img/user_icon.png') }}" alt="" />
         @endif
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
         <textarea  class="comment_input" placeholder="Join the discussion..." @keydown.enter.prevent="postComment({{$current_user->id}}, {{$article->id}})" v-model.trim="reply_comment"></textarea>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Method:

```
  methods: {
    replyBox: function(comment) {
      comment.isActive = !comment.isActive;
    }
  },
```

Alternatively, you can extract this in a separate component:

In a .vue file:

```
<template>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="initial" v-on:click.prevent="replyBox(comment)">REPLY</a>

    <div id="reply-box-@{{comment.id}}" class="reply-box" v-bind:class="{active: comment.isActive}">
      <div class="user_comment row">
       <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
         <div class="user_profile_image {{ isset($current_user->personal_user) ? 'bg_blue' : 'bg_green'}}">
           @if(isset($current_user->avatar) && $current_user->avatar != '')
           <img src="{{ avatar_path($current_user->avatar)}}" alt="" />
         @else
           <img src="{{ home_asset('img/user_icon.png') }}" alt="" />
         @endif
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
         <textarea  class="comment_input" placeholder="Join the discussion..." @keydown.enter.prevent="postComment({{$current_user->id}}, {{$article->id}})" v-model.trim="reply_comment"></textarea>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'comment',
    props: ['comment']
    methods: {
      replyBox: function(comment) {
        comment.isActive = !comment.isActive;
      }
    },
  };
</script>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<ul class="comment_list" v-for="comment in all_comments">
  <comment :comment="comment"></comment>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

`<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>`

isActive is your condition which has to be meet